# Why did the swiper-wrapper get ended up so big?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

I use [swiper.js](https://idangero.us/swiper/).
Below, there is the actual demo site.

---

### Problem

There is a mystery gap below..

[image: like this]

---

[image: this]

This turned out to be probably due to `swiper-wrapper` or `swiper-slide`,
but why did this happen?

How to this fit the element? (How can I fix this space?)

---

### Demo site

Real site is [here](https://mqs2.com/problemPage/problem.html)

[JSFiddle (fullscreen)](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/0zheL29w/3/embedded/result/)
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/0zheL29w/3/)

Could you please give me a hand?

---

### Add: Current status

▼ If I change the width or height of the browser, it will be ended up covered with the next slide.

[image: like this]
[image: like this]

▲ When I checked with the developer tool of Chrome, it turned out that the height of the contents part is very large. (It may be easy to understand if you look at the bottom of gif.)

How can I eliminate the extra height at the bottom of the contents?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things to do here:

### **1.** Correct width and height of .`wrap` and `#content`

You give them specified diemensions (width and height with percent and calc()).
But then you expend those values by using padding and border.
Both, padding and border by default **expand diemensions** of a block element.
Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to them both, and then they will have width and height you set - the padding and border (! but nor margin) **will be put inside them**.

### 2. Add `max-height: 100%;` to `.swiper-container`

`height: auto;` means that element will get height of the content that is inside of it.

If you set height (or max-height) with a value (pixels, percent .. whatever) it will refer to the parent.

You could also add `overflow: hidden;` instead of max-height to `#content` - overall effect would be the same - but it makes more sense to limit the height of `.swiper-container`.

```
.wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.swiper-container {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hypermotion/pqr1b687/10/)

Comment: Thank you very much!
Oh I see. Certainly the lower space has disappeared!
However, can you lend me some more hands?
For now, if I change the width or height of the browser, it will be ended up covered with the next slide.
When I checked with the developer tool of Chrome, it turned out that the height of the contents part is very large.
I want to variable because Flexbox, but how can I eliminate the extra height at the bottom of the contents? (I added the current situation to the question. Please take a look.)

Comment: Does this gives you what you are looking for?:
/* Get rid of nasty vertical scrollbar that appears on #content element */
#content {
overflow-y: hidden;
}
.swiper-container {
height:100%;
max-height:100%;
}

Comment: The slides get right height.
The problem STILL IS with ech slide's content.
They simply are higher then screen when you make it small and since they are not hidden they overlap.

You can set overflow: hidden; for each .swiper-slide
The content will be gone, but won't overlap.The right thing to do is to make sure that each slides content is responsive and always fits into one device screen.

Comment: I don't think it's even logicaly possible to have three slides and sometimes move slides by 100% screen size .. but when they are longer ... how would you see that? ?? swipe first slide once until the end of it is visible and then slide to second slide?

It makes no sense .. use one long page for mobile devices if you can't make content responsive.

Anyway .. my solution here works for Desktops

Answer (score 0):

I used `max-content` on swiper slide and that works for me

```css
.swiper-slide {
  height: -webkit-max-content!important;
  height: -moz-max-content!important;
  height: max-content!important;
}
```